# How to change Process[Task, ByteVector] to json object?

Tags: json, scala, process, stream, scalaz

I use http4s and scalaz.steam._

```
def usersService = HttpService{
  case req @ POST -> Root / "check" / IntVar(userId) =>{
    //val jsonobj=parse(req.as[String])
    val taskAsJson:String = write[req.body]
    Ok(read[Task](taskAsJson))
  }
}
```

For http4s, the request can get body as the type **Process[Task, ByteVector]**
The Process is `scalaz.stream.process` class. You can find details on scalaz.

I want to write a Task here can deal with JSON ByteVector and translate into a Map (like HashMap), layer by layer.

I mean, for example:

```
 {
       "id":"12589",
       "customers":[{
           "id": "898970",
           "name":"Frank"
            ...
           },
           ]
   }
```

I do not know how to write the function via `scalaz.stream.Process` to change the JSON to mapobject.

I want response and to parse the JSON object, returning another refactored JSON object; how can I do it?

Comment: can you clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: @Ven already change the question